# Open account settings activity Android TV

Tags: android, adb, broadcast

I want to open the android TV account settings using a adb command.

This is the view I would like to open

[image]

I have tried to use this command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.accounts.AccountSettingsActivity
```

But I get the following error:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.tv.settings/.accounts.AccountSettingsActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class{com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.accounts.AccountSettingsActivity} does not exist.
```

Does anyone know how to open this view directly?

Answer (score 1):

Search logcat for a line like this one when you open Accounts & Sign in (*this one is from a phone not an Andtoid TV*):

```
ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings (has extras)} from uid 1000
```

and you will have the Activity name.

Comment: In my particular case it seems to be a fragment of a different Activity which is com.android.tv.settings/com.android.tv.settings.MainSettings  but I have no idea if a certain fragment can be opened using a adb command. I also do not see anything in the logcat feed.